# Why does the select break off?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select  m.matnr, m.hkl, m.lok_nr from Bestand M,

(select b.matnr, b.hkl, b.lok_nr from BESTAND B, LAGER_LOKATION L
 where ((b.matnr = l.matnr and b.hkl = l.hkl and b.lok_nr = l.lok_nr 
 and b.best_frei = 0 and l.greiflok = 'J' and l.status = 2) or
       (b.matnr = l.matnr and b.hkl = l.hkl and b.lok_nr = l.lok_nr 
 and b.best_frei > 0 and l.greiflok = 'N' and l.status = 2))
) Bedingung_1,


 ( select s.matnr, s.hkl, s.ziel_lok_nr from SONDER_AUFTRAG S, 
  LAGER_LOKATION L2
  where s.matnr = l2.matnr and s.hkl = l2.hkl and s.status = 611 and 
  s.ziel_lok_nr = l2.lok_nr and l2.greiflok ='N'
 ) Bedingung_2

where

m.matnr = Bedingung_1.matnr and m.matnr not in Bedingung_2.matnr
group by m.matnr, m.hkl, m.lok_nr;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. (Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time.)

Comment: comment this  'and m.matnr not in Bedingung_2.matnr' then   try. does this run?

Comment: Why does the select break off - I have no idea what this means

Comment: not in  Bedingung_2.matnr is invalid should be not in (Bedingung_2.matnr) to syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select  m.matnr, m.hkl, m.lok_nr from Bestand M 
    left join
    (select b.matnr, b.hkl, b.lok_nr from BESTAND B, LAGER_LOKATION L
     where ((b.matnr = l.matnr and b.hkl = l.hkl and b.lok_nr = l.lok_nr 
     and b.best_frei = 0 and l.greiflok = 'J' and l.status = 2) or
           (b.matnr = l.matnr and b.hkl = l.hkl and b.lok_nr = l.lok_nr 
     and b.best_frei > 0 and l.greiflok = 'N' and l.status = 2))
    ) Bedingung_1 on m.matnr = Bedingung_1.matnr
    where
    m.matnr not in 
( select s.matnr from SONDER_AUFTRAG S, 
      LAGER_LOKATION L2
      where s.matnr = l2.matnr and s.hkl = l2.hkl and s.status = 611 and 
      s.ziel_lok_nr = l2.lok_nr and l2.greiflok ='N'
     )
    group by m.matnr, m.hkl, m.lok_nr;
```

Try this.